# $X$ and $Y$ are Compact Metric Spaces Such that for a continuous surjective $f$, $f^{-1}[\{y\}]$ is connected

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $X$ and $Y$ be compact metric spaces and let $f: X \rightarrow Y$ be a continuous onto map with the property that $f^{-1}[\{y\}]$ is connected for every $y \in Y$. Show that if $Y$ is connected then so is $X$.

As $X$ is compact, I know that $\bigcup^\infty_{y \in Y} f^{-1}[\{y\}]$ is an open covering of $X$. Hence there exists a finite subcovering $\bigcup^k_{y_i \in Y} f^{-1}[\{y_i\}]$ of $X$. Each of these open sets must be connected, but I can't manage to show that their union must also be connected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HINT: Suppose that $H$ and $K$ are disjoint closed subsets of $X$ such that $X=H\cup K$.

- Show that $f[H]$ and $f[K]$ are closed sets in $Y$.
- Show that for each $y\in Y$, $f^{-1}[\{y\}]\subseteq H$ or $f^{-1}[\{y\}]\subseteq K$.
- Conclude that $f[H]\cap f[K]=\varnothing$.

Clearly $f[H]\cup f[K]=Y$, and $Y$ is connected, so ... ?